# Delay the rendering of a component in vue

Tags: vuejs2

I've created a component in vue which wraps a vue-apexchart donut graph. As soon as the page loads and this component is loaded, the vue-apexchart animates and displays a small graph. 
Now I would like to instantiate multiple of these components from a dataset side by side. Instead of the components to all load an animate at the same time, I would like a small rendering delay to give it an overall nice effect. Something like this would be nice:

```
  <donut :items="series1"></donut>
  <donut :items="series2" delay=1500></donut>
```

The vue-apexchart doesent support initialization delays, and as far as I can see there isn't any vue-specific official solution to delay the rendering of components. 
I've tried to put a setTimeout in any of the component hooks to stall the initialization, 
I´ve also tried to inject the all the graph DOM in the template element on a v-html tag in a setTimeout, but apexchart doesent notice this new dom content, and vue doesent notice the html bindings either.

I´ve created this fiddle which loads two instances of a graph:
https://jsfiddle.net/4f2zkq5c/7/

Any creative suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have the possibility to reformat your data, you can build an array of series objects, add a `show: true/false` property and iterate it:

```js
//template
<div v-for="serie in series">
  <donut :items="serie.data" v-if="serie.show"></donut>
</div>

//script
data: function() {
  return {
    series: [
      { data: [44, 55, 41, 17, 15], show: false },
      { data: [10, 20, 30], show: false },
    ]
  }
}
```

Now you can create a `setTimeout` function which will change the `serie.show` to `true` by incrementing the delay based on the serie index.
Then add the function on the mounted hook:

```js
methods: {
  delayedShow (serie, idx) {
    let delay = 1500 * idx
    setTimeout(() => {
      serie.show = true
    }, delay)
  }
},
mounted () {
  this.series.forEach((serie, idx) => {
    this.delayedShow(serie, idx)
  })
}
```

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/xtvdheo0/)

Answer (score 10):

There are several ways you can do this, and it depends on whether you can actually modify the `<animated-component>` logic yourself:

### 1. Use VueJS's built-in `<transition-group>` to handle list rendering

VueJS comes with a very handy support for transitions that you can use to sequentially show your `<animated-component>`. You will need to use a custom animation library (like VelocityJS) and simply store the delay in the element's dataset, e.g. `v-bind:data-delay="500"`. [VueJS docs has a very good example on how to introduce staggered transitions for `<transition-group>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Staggering-List-Transitions), and the example below is largely adapted from it.

You then use the [`beforeAppear` and `appear` hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitions-on-Initial-Render) to set the opacity of the individual children of the `<transition-group>`.

```js
Vue.component('animated-component', {
  template: '#animatedComponentTemplate',
  props: {
    data: {
      required: true
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dataset: {
      first: 'Hello world',
      second: 'Foo bar',
      third: 'Lorem ipsum'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    beforeAppear: function(el) {
      el.style.opacity = 0;
    },
    appear: function(el, done) {
      var delay = +el.dataset.delay;
      setTimeout(function() {
        Velocity(
          el, {
            opacity: 1
          }, {
            complete: done
          }
        )
      }, delay)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.3/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <transition-group name="fade" v-on:before-appear="beforeAppear" v-on:appear="appear">
    <animated-component v-bind:data="dataset.first" v-bind:key="0"> </animated-component>
    <animated-component v-bind:data="dataset.second" v-bind:key="1" v-bind:data-delay="500"> </animated-component>
    <animated-component v-bind:data="dataset.third" v-bind:key="2" v-bind:data-delay="1000"> </animated-component>
  </transition-group>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="animatedComponentTemplate">
  <div>
    <h1>Animated Component</h1>
    {{ data }}
  </div>
</script>
```

### 2. Let `<animated-component>` handle its own rendering

In this example, you simply pass the a number to the `delay` property (remember to use `v-bind:delay="<number>"` so that you pass a number and not a string). Then, in the `<animated-component>`'s mounted lifecycle hook, you use a timer to toggle the visibility of the component itself.

The technique on how you want to show the initially hidden component is up to you, but here I simply apply an initial opacity of `0` and then transition it after a setTimeout.

```js
Vue.component('animated-component', {
  template: '#animatedComponentTemplate',
  props: {
    data: {
      required: true
    },
    delay: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      isVisible: false
    };
  },
  computed: {
    styleObject: function() {
      return {
        opacity: this.isVisible ? 1 : 0
      };
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    var that = this;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      that.isVisible = true;
    }, that.delay);
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dataset: {
      first: 'Hello world',
      second: 'Foo bar',
      third: 'Lorem ipsum'
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.animated-component {
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <animated-component v-bind:data="dataset.first"> </animated-component>
  <animated-component v-bind:data="dataset.second" v-bind:delay="500"> </animated-component>
  <animated-component v-bind:data="dataset.third" v-bind:delay="1000"> </animated-component>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="animatedComponentTemplate">
  <div class="animated-component" v-bind:style="styleObject">
    <h1>Animated Component, delay: {{ delay }}</h1>
    {{ data }}
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your comprehensive answer. I don´t think I can use any of your suggestions, because my component is wrapping the Vue apexchart library (https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/pie-charts/update-donut/) The apexchart graph controls it´s own animation cycle which I cannot delay. The only way for me to delay it is by delaying the component I think.
Your first suggestion uses already rendered objects which are first hidden and then shown.
Your second suggestion is kind of like the same problem - the graph is already rendered and the animation is done, when I later show it.

Comment: @Farsen This is a reason why it's important you include an MCVE in your question: in your original question there is no indication of what restrictions you are facing, let alone what library you are using.

Comment: you´re right, sorry about that. I´ve updated my question now.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem with ApexCharts Pie Charts being redrawn rapidly in sequence due to data being pulled from a pinia store mutating too quickly for the chart to keep up, leading to ugly errors in the console.

I resolved the issue by using a boolean ref in a v-if="showChart" on the component and then using a setTimeout to trigger a delayed drawing of the chart:

```
import { ref } from "vue";
import useStore from "@/store/myChartStore";

const store = useStore();

const showChart = ref(false);
store.$subscribe((mutation, state) =>{
    showChart.value = false;
    setTimeout(()=> {
        showChart.value = true;
    }
    , 100);
});
```

If you're not using a store, you may find another way to watch the initial availability of the chart data and then delay the rendering using that same approach.